# Mobile browser issue with textarea resize

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, textarea, height

I am working in React.js and have `textarea` elements that dynamically expand and contract based on the size of the user's input. The intended functionality is as follows:

[image: Working correctly in a desktop context]

This works correctly in a desktop context. However, on any mobile or tablet in a modern browser (tested Safari, Chrome and Firefox) the `textarea` element only expands, it does not contract when content is deleted.

At first I thought it might have something to do with the `onChange` handler I was employing, however, the same issue remains when swapping it out with an `onInput` handler. So I believe the issue resides in the `resize()` method.

Does anyone have an idea of why I'm experiencing this issue?

I have created a style-free fiddle to share with you the basic functionality. Interestingly, the bug doesn't occur in the JSFiddle simulator on a mobile device, but if you take the same code and put it in another react environment, the bug occurs on a mobile device in modern browsers.

```js
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Textarea value="This is a test" maxLength={500}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Textarea extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: this.props.value
        ? this.props.maxLength && this.props.maxLength > 0
          ? this.props.value.length < this.props.maxLength
            ? this.props.value
            : this.props.value.substring(0, this.props.maxLength)
          : this.props.value
        : '',
      remaining: this.props.value
        ? this.props.value.length < this.props.maxLength
          ? this.props.maxLength - this.props.value.length
          : 0
        : this.props.maxLength
    };

    this.textAreaRef = React.createRef();
    
    this.textAreaHeight = null;
    this.textAreaoffSetHeight = null;
  }
  
  
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize);
    this.resize();
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resize);
  }
  
  handleChange = event => {
    const target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    this.setState({
      value: target.value,
      remaining: target.value
        ? target.value.length < this.props.maxLength
          ? this.props.maxLength - target.value.length
          : 0
        : this.props.maxLength
    });

    this.resize();
  };
  
  resize = () => {
    const node = this.textAreaRef.current;

    node.style.height = '';

    const style = window.getComputedStyle(node, null);

    let heightOffset =
      parseFloat(style.borderTopWidth) + parseFloat(style.borderBottomWidth);

    this.textAreaoffSetHeight = node.offsetTop;

    this.textAreaHeight = node.scrollHeight + heightOffset;

    node.style.height = this.textAreaHeight + 'px';

    this.resizeBorder();
    this.resizeParentNode();
  };

  resizeBorder = () => {
    const textAreaSize = this.textAreaHeight;
    const node = this.textAreaRef.current;
    const borderNode = node.parentNode.querySelector(
      '.textarea__border'
    );
    
    if (borderNode !== null) {
      borderNode.style.top =
        this.textAreaoffSetHeight + textAreaSize - 1 + 'px';
    }
  };

  resizeParentNode = () => {
    const node = this.textAreaRef.current;
    const parentNode = node.parentNode;
    
    if (parentNode !== null) {
      parentNode.style.height = this.textAreaHeight + 40 + 'px';
    }
  };

    render() {
    return (
      <div className={'textarea'}>
        <textarea
          ref={this.textAreaRef}
          className={
            !this.state.value
              ? 'textarea__input'
              : 'textarea__input active'
          }
          value={this.state.value}
          maxLength={
            this.props.maxLength && this.props.maxLength > 0 ? this.props.maxLength : null
          }
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <div className={'textarea__message'}>
            {this.state.remaining <= 0
              ? `You've reached ${this.props.maxLength} characters`
              : `${this.state.remaining} characters remaining`}
          </div>
      </div>
    );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Application />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main id="app">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</main>
```

Comment: I have now added a more appropriate fiddle, and a reasonable bounty

Comment: The jsfiddle you provided seems unnecessarily complicated.

Here's a GitHub repo of mine, can you try this one and see if you also see the same bug or not? https://github.com/MartinDawson/react-fluid-textarea

Comment: @danMad I have reproduced you code from JsFiddle in a React Context [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/2v5y8x17nj) and it seems to work without any weird behaviour. Can you confirm ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem anyways

Comment: All works fine in my mobile, I guess

Comment: Share your github repository.

Comment: Can you add more about your test identification browser?

Comment: it works fine on my mobile browser

Comment: It works fine in my mobile. deployed version  - [check here](https://indian-fox.netlify.com/)

Comment: @danMad as it seems to be working for everyone, I would suggest upgrading your other plugins, assessing what you can potentially remove, and also use the highest possible version of react. It's a funny one alright (although I couldn't reproduce it).. Maybe it's a sign that you deserve a new phone for all your hard work! :)

Comment: Using Laura's Fiddle I also could not reproduce the bug, and had the textarea resizing with the content. But in a codepen I made, where I was just messing with a textarea element, I found a `<div>` with a `contentEditable` attribute was generally responding better than the <textarea>.  But, of course, this it neither accessible nor semantic.

Comment: Since you mentioned Safari, I assume you checked it on your IOS device. Since all browsers on IOS actually work with the same "webkit" engine, you did not have 3 seperate failures, just one.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're modifying the DOM directly (or trying to) instead of modifying state and allowing React to flow properly.  You modify the DOM elements properties in `resize()` then any input change will immediate call `handleChange(e)` and re-flow your DOM overwriting the modifications.

NEVER MIX REACT WITH DOM TOUCHING!!!

Change your `resize` function to behave like your `handleChange(e)` function and set variables within the state which control those properties during the `render()` of the mark-up.

Comment: I liked when you said: NEVER MIX REACT WITH DOM TOUCHING!!!